# How can I alter FontAwesomeIcon properties outside the initial <FontAwesomeIcon /> call in React Native?

Tags: react-native, colors, size, font-awesome

I currently have a modal where the user can pick from a large flatlist of icons. All have size: '45' and color: 'white'. When a user selects an icon, the modal is closed and their selected icon appears on the card (this feature is one that allows the user to create a custom card).

I then have a feature that allows the user to change the line colour from white to black and visa versa on the card to contrast with their selected background colour. I would also like the colour of the icon to change with the lines, but I cannot find a solution! The icon object itself is read-only and using a StyleSheet seems to only apply styles when it is referenced within the original call like:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={archive} style = {styles.text} />
```

I can't seem to wrap it in a styled view and then change the style from there.

Any ideas on how to alter the colour? And the size while I'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can make state like this :

```
const [style,setStyle]=useState()
```

You change state with user color, and apply it to your FontAwesome icon

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={archive} style = {style} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers! I ended up creating a library to reference and just passed the library prefix (fab, far, fas) and the icon name (coffee, archive, wifi). Then used:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={[icon.props.icon[0], icon.props.icon[1]]} style ={blabla} size = {blabla} />
```

Meaning I can now manipulate the size and colour wherever I want! Very handy.